# Backward animation on pure JavaScript in the slider

Tags: javascript

How to make, that when you click on the next slide, the animation starts with the current slide. Also when the button is back. When we reach the last slide and click on the next slide, the first slider moves next.

**It is necessary to make(on pure js) a slider as a "Single Item" [here](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)**

How to make, that when you click on the next slide, the animation starts with the current slide. Also when the button is back. When we reach the last slide and click on the next slide, the first slider moves next.

How to make, that when you click on the next slide, the animation starts with the current slide. Also when the button is back. When we reach the last slide and click on the next slide, the first slider moves next.
The slider should work on any number of images from 1 to 10.

When you click on the right control (arrow) of the slider, when the slider reaches the last image, the first image should also go to the right. Wrong option: the slider scrolls to the left until the first image.

If you click many times on the slider during the animation, the slides should not be switched until the animation ends. For example: If I click 20 times on the control (arrow) of the slider during the animation - nothing happens. When the animation was over and I clicked 21 times - the slide switched to the next one.

When you click on the point at the bottom of the slider, I must go to the corresponding. slide. If the current slide is the one I clicked on, nothing should happen.

```js
var slideIndex=0;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n){
 showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n){
 showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n){
 var i;
 var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("picture");
 var mySlides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
 var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

 if(n > slides.length){
  slideIndex = 1;
 }
 console.log(slides.length);
 if(n < 1){
  slideIndex = slides.length;
 }
 for(i=0; i < dots.length; i++){
  dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace("active","");
 }
 if(n == 1){
  var t = 0;
 } if (n == 2) {
  var t = 1
 } if (n ==3) {
  var t = 2
 }
 function animate(options) {

  var start = performance.now();

  requestAnimationFrame(function animate(time) {
   // timeFraction от 0 до 1
   var timeFraction = (time - start) / options.duration;
   if (timeFraction > 1) timeFraction = 1;

   
   var progress = options.timing(timeFraction)

   options.draw(progress);

   if (timeFraction < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
   }

  });
 }
 animate({
  duration: 2000,
  timing: function(timeFraction) {
   return timeFraction;
  },
  draw: function(progress) {
   mySlides[0].style.marginLeft = progress * (-1000) * t + 'px';
  }
 });
 console.log(slideIndex);
 dots[slideIndex-1].className+= " active";

}
```

```css
.slidershow-container{
 max-width: 1000px;
 position: relative;
 margin: auto;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 350px;
}
.prev, .next{
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 width: auto;
 margin-top: -22px;
 padding: 16px;
 color:white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 18px;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
 border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
.next{
 right: 8px;
 border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.mySlides{
 text-align: center;
 max-height: 700px;
 width: 3000px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 height: 505px;
}
.picture {
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    float: left;
}
img {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 350px;
}
.numbertext {
 display: inline;
}
.dot{
 cursor: pointer;
 height: 13px;
 width: 13px;
 margin: 0 2px;
 background-color: #bbb;
 border-radius: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
}
.active, .dot:hover{
 background-color: #717171;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="slidershow-container">
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="picture"><img style="background-color: black;" src=""></div>
   <div class="picture"><img style="background-color: #ff4b5a;" src=""></div>
   <div class="picture"><img style="background-color: #36ff31;" src=""></div>
  </div>
  <a onclick="plusSlides(-1)" class="prev">&#10094</a>
  <a onclick="plusSlides(1)" class="next">&#10095</a>
 </div>
 <br>
 <div style="text-align:center;">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>

 </div>
 <div class="div"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: RIM, I like your detailed requirements list.  Instead of listing out a bunch of requirements and asking for a solution, can you stub out some javascript event handlers that show the expected behavior? Maybe set a flag to say whether the slider is animating, check that when a button is pressed and output a message like "move to next slide" or "do nothing" if the animation should still be in process?

Comment: Some sliders use an inner "track" to hold the slides. They clone the first slide(s) on to the end and clone the last slide(s) on to the beginning. Then you just animate the position of the track. Another option is to keep track of the current slide, locate the element that should animate in and place it to the right or left depending on the direction to slide, and then animate the current slide out of view while you animate the next one into view.